# Retrieve list of path name from igraph all_simple_paths

Tags: r, list, igraph

I have a directed cyclical matrix and need to extract all the simple paths between any i and j.

The following is my ex. matrix:

```
>M2<-matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1), 5, byrow=T)
>colnames(M2)<-c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
>row.names(M2)=colnames(M2)
>M2
  A B C D E
A 1 1 0 0 0
B 1 1 1 1 0
C 0 1 1 1 0
D 0 1 0 1 1
E 0 0 0 1 1
```

I use `igraph` to convert the matrix to a graph object using the `graph_from_adjency_matrix` function.

```
>graph<-graph_from_adjacency_matrix(M2, mode=c("directed"), weighted=NULL, diag=F, add.colnames=NULL, add.rownames=NA)
>graph
IGRAPH DN-- 5 9 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] A->B B->A B->C B->D C->B C->D D->B D->E E->D
```

And from there I use the `all_simple_paths` function to get all the simple paths between i and j. And here starts my questions.

1) I can specify the j (argument `to` has `to=V(graph)`) to be all possible end vertices. But I can't specify the `from` argument to calculate the paths looking for all vertices has possible starting points. I have to specify each of my variables at a time. Any solution?

2) The `all_simple_path` function works well and gives me all the simple paths between i and j, e.g. for simple paths starting in `A` and ending in any possible j:

```
>Simple_path_list<-all_simple_paths(graph, from ="A", to=V(graph), mode = c("out"))
>Simple_path_list
[[1]]
+ 2/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B

[[2]]
+ 3/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B C

[[3]]
+ 4/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B C D

[[4]]
+ 5/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B C D E

[[5]]
+ 3/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B D

[[6]]
+ 4/5 vertices, named:
[1] A B D E
```

My problem is, I need to collect all those paths and put on a list, e.g.:

```
Paths
A B
A B C
A B C D
A B C D E 
A B D
A B D E
```

I tried to create a list and call for the path names using the normal `list<-Simple_path_list[1]` or so, but I always retrieve, together with the paths, the information on the number of vertices involved (e.g., `+ 4/5 vertices, named`). Any idea on how can I retrieve solely the paths name and not the other information?

Comment: Ok, found an answer to the point 1) by using
     `>lapply(V(graph) , function(x) all_simple_paths(graph, from=x))`

It gives now a list of all the possible simple paths for each beginning variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lapply` function on `all_simple_paths` makes a list of lists (i.e. a list of each vertex's list of paths). Simplify the list of lists to a list using `unlist(..., recursive = F)` and then use `names` or `igraph`'s `as_ids` to extract the vertex ids solo.

```
library(igraph)
M2<-matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1), 5, byrow=T)
colnames(M2)<-c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
row.names(M2)=colnames(M2)
M2
graph<-graph_from_adjacency_matrix(M2, mode=c("directed"), weighted=NULL, diag=F, add.colnames=NULL, add.rownames=NA)
l <- unlist(lapply(V(graph) , function(x) all_simple_paths(graph, from=x)), recursive = F)
paths <- lapply(1:length(l), function(x) as_ids(l[[x]]))
```

This produces:

```
> paths
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"

[[3]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

[[4]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"

[[5]]
[1] "A" "B" "D"

[[6]]
[1] "A" "B" "D" "E"

[[7]]
[1] "B" "A"

[[8]]
[1] "B" "C"

[[9]]
[1] "B" "C" "D"

[[10]]
[1] "B" "C" "D" "E"

[[11]]
[1] "B" "D"

[[12]]
[1] "B" "D" "E"

[[13]]
[1] "C" "B"

[[14]]
[1] "C" "B" "A"

[[15]]
[1] "C" "B" "D"

[[16]]
[1] "C" "B" "D" "E"

[[17]]
[1] "C" "D"

[[18]]
[1] "C" "D" "B"

[[19]]
[1] "C" "D" "B" "A"

[[20]]
[1] "C" "D" "E"

[[21]]
[1] "D" "B"

[[22]]
[1] "D" "B" "A"

[[23]]
[1] "D" "B" "C"

[[24]]
[1] "D" "E"

[[25]]
[1] "E" "D"

[[26]]
[1] "E" "D" "B"

[[27]]
[1] "E" "D" "B" "A"

[[28]]
[1] "E" "D" "B" "C"
```

#### Addition

For `all_shortest_paths` you must subset the list of paths for each node to *exclude* the geodesic information.

```
l <- lapply(V(graph), function(x) all_shortest_paths(graph, from = x))
l <- lapply(l, function(x) x[[-2]])
l <- unlist(l, recursive = F)
paths <- lapply(1:length(l), function(x) as_ids(l[[x]]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Paqmo both for the correction (I was copying directly from my txt file and forgot to correct the names, so thanks for the fix) and many thanks for the answer. This works wonderfully!!

Comment: @paqmo replacing to `all_shortest_paths` gives an error. Can this be done with that function as well?

Comment: @Mel, see addition to the answer